# fb.ui (js sdk) doesn't work on subpages

Tags: javascript, sdk

I am using the latest fb js sdk with the default initialization:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '<?php echo $config->app_id; ?>',
        xfbml      : true,
        status     : true,
        version    : 'v2.3'
    });

  };
```

On the first page of my facebook page tab the fb.ui function works fine, but if I go to a subpage and try to share I get the following error: "An error occurred. Please try later"

But the rest of the fb js calls work fine, like if I want to retrive the fb id, I don't get any error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying 1 million things, I found the problem by myself:

You have to add your domain name in facebook developers, under "App Domains".

Put www.domain.com or without www, depending on what URL you are using the the secur page tab, canvas or website.

That fixed the problem for me.